# Why does OpenCV think I am using a non-planar calibration rig?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm playing with a simulated camera rig to try and understand how OpenCV's calib3d module works and performs.

I've created an artificial set of object points in 3D space corresponding to a flat grid of nine points at z=50:

```
obj_pts = np.zeros((9, 3), dtype='float32')
obj_pts[0] = np.array([40, 40, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[1] = np.array([50, 40, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[2] = np.array([60, 40, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[3] = np.array([40, 50, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[4] = np.array([50, 50, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[5] = np.array([60, 50, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[6] = np.array([40, 60, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[7] = np.array([50, 60, 50], dtype='float32')
obj_pts[8] = np.array([60, 60, 50], dtype='float32')
```

Which I have then imaged using `cv2.projectPoints()` after creating an artificial camera:

```
rvec = (0, 0, 0)  # rotation relative to the frame
tvec = (0, 0, 0)  # translation relative to the frame
distCoeffs = (0, 0, 0, 0)
cameraMatrix = np.zeros((3, 3))
focalLength = 50
cx = 0
cy = 0
setupCameraMatrix(cameraMatrix, focalLength, cx, cy) # my own routine

img_pts, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(obj_pts, rvec, tvec, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs)
```

Projected into the image plane using the parameters above, the image points look like this (red point just indicates bottom left corner for orientation):

[image: Plot of the artificial image points projected into image plane]

And finally I'm attempting to retrieve the original camera calibration:

```
obj_pts_list = [obj_pts]
img_pts_list = [img_pts]
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_pts_list, img_pts_list, (200, 200), None, None)
```

However this final step gives this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified) in cvCalibrateCamera2, file /tmp/opencv20150527-4924-hjrvz/opencv-2.4.11/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 1592
```

My question isn't about how to fix this error per se - but rather why is it being thrown in the first place? Why does this setup constitute a non-planar rig when all object points lie in the same plane? Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV expects `z = 0` as it is the case for planar calibration targets.

Looking into the code, `OpenCV` checks this value as follows:

```
Scalar mean, sdv;
meanStdDev(matM, mean, sdv);
if( fabs(mean[2]) > 1e-5 || fabs(sdv[2]) > 1e-5 )
        CV_Error( CV_StsBadArg,
"For non-planar calibration rigs the initial intrinsic matrix must be specified" );
```

which means that setting z other than 0 triggers the error. You must then use `z = 0` unless using a non-planar calibration target.